# Writing Conditional Code for Internet Explorer WITHIN a Javascript file

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, browser-detection

I'd like to know if it's possible to write conditional javascript **within a javascript file** for Internet Explorer.

i.e. something like this...

```
if (is IE7) {
    do this } else {
    do this instead
});
```

I know I can load a completely different script for IE using conditional comments in the head, but I only want to change a small piece of code and so loading a completely different sheet would be an 'expensive' way to do that.

Comment: You might want to look into [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com).

Comment: Pertinent:  http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/detect-browser/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jquery you code do this

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == '6.0') {
     //do IE specific code
}
```

Comment: This is great, exactly what I needed.

For anyone else needing advice here is a reference list for targeting specific browsers http://blog.bestwebframeworks.com/detect-browsers-with-jquery/

Comment: This feature is removed from jQuery, starting at version 1.9.

Answer (score 4):

When writing Javascript, doing **feature detection** is always the way to go instead of **browser detection**. So instead of doing `if (IE7)` do `if (feature)`.

For example, if you want to know if your browser supports `getElementsByClassName()`, instead of checking the browser version, you check for the existence of the function ( `if (document.getElementsByClassName)` ).

**Please read this great article:**

[Object detection on Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html)

> If you want to know whether the
>   browser that views your page supports
>   certain objects you want to use in
>   your code, you should never EVER use a
>   browser detect. Sure, you know that
>   this–and–that browser will support
>   your code while such–and–so browser
>   won’t. But how about other browsers,
>   obscure browsers?

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you, but feature detection is not the way to go when I am just trying to cater for IE7 bugs.

Comment: @Sparrohawx Most of the time it is the way. But as we have no examples, I cannot prove this.

Answer (score 2):

Not within the JavaScript file directly.

A few alternatives would be:

Using a *global* variable before the script is loaded to check in your JavaScript file. This is a bit of a hybrid approach and could get *messy*, but it's guaranteed IE detection.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var is_ie = true;
</script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile.js"></script>
```

Or, a more traditional approach using browser or [object detection](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html) within the JavaScript file.

Comment: +1 It looks messy, but if you really want browser detection (which is only right in certain edge cases), this seems to be the best way.

Comment: This is a far more stable solution. Sadly, conditional comments get passed over time and again for fallacious UA sniffing.

Comment: +1 This is my preferred method as well, though it still feels a bit dirty ;-)

Comment: This is a good solution but the question says within a JavaScript file

Comment: @Nathan, yes and my answer clearly states *Not within the JavaScript file directly*. Thanks for the two week delayed downvote though.

Answer (score 2):

[Conditional compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment#Conditional_Comment_in_JScript) is exactly what you are looking for.

```
<script>
/*@cc_on

  @if (@_jscript_version == 5.7 && window.XMLHttpRequest)
    document.write("You are using IE7");

  @end

@*/
</script>
```

Comment: Interesting. I'd never heard of Conditional Compilation before. +1

Answer (score 1):

**Despite the fact that this is an answer to the original question, this is NOT what you should do. So don't do it!**

Why not work out which browser you are using and store that in a variable in javascript. Then you can have if statemenets and the like in your javascript. e.g. If I am IE then do this, otherwise do that. You get the idea!

Have you seen this? [Browser sniffing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134579/browser-sniffing)

The salient bit:

```
var is = {
  ff: window.globalStorage,
  ie: document.all && !window.opera,
  ie6: !window.XMLHttpRequest,
  ie7: document.all && window.XMLHttpRequest && !XDomainRequest && !window.opera,
  ie8: document.documentMode==8,
  opera: Boolean(window.opera),
  chrome: Boolean(window.chrome),
  safari: window.getComputedStyle && !window.globalStorage && !window.opera
}
```

Comment: -1 for showing how to use feature detection the *wrong* way. There is no guarantee that the existence or non existence of certain features means a particular browser. Browsers change all the time, implementing new features and (rarely) deprecating old ones.

Comment: Ouch! Isn't that how jQuery does it behind the scenes? And isn't that pretty much what everybody else's answer has said? Did you -1 everybody else? Seriously though, if this answer is wrong, what is the correct answer to this question? And as an aside, how can the features of IE6, IE7 or IE8 change, when they have all been superseded?

Comment: That isn't, actually, what other answers have said. Other answers have used actual user agent sniffing, conditional comments, or feature detection. This uses features of the browser to come to conclusions about which browser it is. Firefox may mean the existence of `window.globalStorage` but the existence of `window.globalStorage` does not necessarily mean Firefox.

Comment: Oh okay, fair enough. There are A LOT of resources that suggest that it's okay to do exactly that, but I can't fault your logic. Hopefully yours and my comments will serve as a warning to anybody else who may have been tempted to use this method which I found elsewhere on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

My go-to script for this is PPK's [BrowserDetect script](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html). It's lightweight, easily understandable, and doesn't require you to use a library. When it's loaded, you can write code like:

```
if (BrowserDetect.browser == "Explorer" && BrowserDetect.version >= 6 && BrowserDetect.version <= 8) {
    // IE6-8 code
{
```

Of course, you should avoid using this at all (reasonable) costs, but there's times where it's  cleaner to quarantine IE-specific code away rather than try to hack around IE-specific functions and bugs.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use jquery, it has a built in browser detect.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/