# Find Browser type & version?

Tags: jquery, browser-detection

Anyone knows of a good and reliable way to find out type & version of a browser installed on client either using JavaScript/jQuery?

Looks like jQuery has some built-in functions, but it is having problems in detecting Chrome. Any other reliable way of doing it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want information about the browser that your visitor uses, and use it for statistics or displaying information to the user, you can use the [jQuery Browser Plugin](http://jquery.thewikies.com/browser/).

> It gives you an object in javascript
>   that contains all of the information
>   about the browser being used.

Be sure to [do feature detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497410/writing-conditional-code-for-internet-explorer-within-a-javascript-file/6497471#6497471) instead of browser detection when you want to determine if a certain feature is available in a browser, apply bugfixes, etc.

*No need to reinvent the wheel.*

Comment: looks like jQuery Browser Plugin is best suited my situation. Thanks for the info regarding feature detection.

Answer (score 7):

**Approach 1:**
**Note:** *Since JQuery 1.3, jQuery.browser is deprecated*

Try this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
 p { color:green; font-weight:bolder; margin:3px 0 0 10px; }
 div { color:blue; margin-left:20px; font-size:14px; }
 span { color:red; }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Browser info: (key : value)</p>

<script>
    jQuery.each(jQuery.browser, function(i, val) {
    $("<div>" + i + " : <span>" + val + "</span>")
               .appendTo( document.body );
    });</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**Approach 2:**

```
// A quick solution without using regexp (to speed up a little).
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toString().toLowerCase();
if ((userAgent.indexOf('safari') != -1) && !(userAgent.indexOf('chrome') != -1)) {
alert('We should be on Safari only!');
}
```

Comment: When I run this program in Chrome, following are the results:Browser info: (key : value)
webkit : true
version : 534.7
safari : true

Comment: Is there any way to differentiage b/w chrome and safari?

Comment: Not to mention that `$.browser` is deprecated since jQuery 1.3. @Arjun Is your goal to display the browser name and version to the user?

Comment: @bazmegakapa - Assume that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Since `$.browser` is removed in jQuery 1.9, use this:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------
// A short snippet for detecting versions of IE in JavaScript
// without resorting to user-agent sniffing
// ----------------------------------------------------------
// If you're not in IE (or IE version is less than 5) then:
//     ie === undefined
// If you're in IE (>=5) then you can determine which version:
//     ie === 7; // IE7
// Thus, to detect IE:
//     if (ie) {}
// And to detect the version:
//     ie === 6 // IE6
//     ie > 7 // IE8, IE9 ...
//     ie < 9 // Anything less than IE9
// ----------------------------------------------------------

// UPDATE: Now using Live NodeList idea from @jdalton

var ie = (function(){

    var undef,
        v = 3,
        div = document.createElement('div'),
        all = div.getElementsByTagName('i');

    while (
        div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE ' + (++v) + ']><i></i><![endif]-->',
        all[0]
    );

    return v > 4 ? v : undef;

}());
```

Comment: A little bit specific to IE.

Comment: @Alex Still more reliable than user agent sniffing.

Comment: Can you complete your answer with browser detection for other major browsers please?