# How to identify the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to find Browser type & version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505027/best-way-to-find-browser-type-version)

In HTML/JavaScript, How can I identify which browser the user is using, and by that choose the code, I mean: if the browser is crhome do that... else ...
Thanks

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, you could use feature detection instead

Comment: Come on you do know how to search something in google don't you? http://www.google.nl/search?hl=en&q=How+to+identify+the+browser

Comment: check `navigator` object in javascript

Comment: 6 questions, 0% of them with accepted answers...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using `navigator` and get all the details. Just make a google search!

```
<div id="example"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

txt = "<p>Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Platform: " + navigator.platform + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "</p>";

document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=txt;

</script>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Its information is incorrect, it shows mozzila & netscape o_o

Comment: Hey, it shows everything. The browser's detail. You have to manipulate it before you use.

Answer (score 4):

It's not recommended to detect browsers since browsers are a moving targets. For example, today Chrome doesn't support feature X but several months later it starts supporting it. If you simply put

```
// Here I detect Chrome browser without a third-party library
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') === -1) {
    doFeatureX()
else {
    console.log('Sorry, no Feature X for you.')
}
```

then you lock Chrome users out *forever*. You should do [*feature detection*](http://ejohn.org/blog/future-proofing-javascript-libraries/) instead and there are quite a few [libraries](http://modernizr.com/) to help you with that:

```
if (Modernizr.geolocation) {
    // do stuff with user's coordinates
}
```

---

But of course *you can detect browsers if you want to*. For example, you'd like to encourage people to upgrade their browser:

```
// Here I'm using jQuery
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) < 9) {
    // show link to http://microsoft.com/ie
} else if ($.browser.mozilla && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) < 11) {
    // show link to http://mozilla.com/firefox
} // etc.
```