# jQuery/Javascript browser detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-detection

I'm sorry if this question has been asked already.  How would I find a user's browser and version using JavaScript or jQuery?  I know that `.browser()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.9.  I am not doing this for code specific purposes, I'm trying to find the browser type for statistical purposes.

Comment: You can read `navigator.userAgent`, but it’s generally better to check the `User-Agent` header on the server side.

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892095/browser-msie-error-after-update-to-jquery-1-9-1

Comment: This is a fairly easy topic to google ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505027/best-way-to-find-browser-type-version

Comment: @elclanrs: That only checks for Internet Explorer.

Comment: @Felk, I've been googling it for about an hour and found nothing helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes is it depecated already in jquery 1.9.

I guess the best code for determining the browser is to usethe traditional

```
navigator.userAgent
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/ | https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID.userAgent

Comment: Note that User Agent is not guaranteed to be correct. Should be fine for statistical purposes though

Comment: But he is going to use this for "Statistical purposes" right? also, by using this code, you don't have to check for compatibility of your jquery because this is recognized by most browsers.

Comment: Yes, I want to do this purely for statistical purposes.

Comment: Then the code above is the best solution for you aim. Please mark this answer if you find this suits your requirement. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

There is a JS Plugin thst you can use:

```
<p>
  Click to <a id="detect_browser"
              href="javascript:void(0);">Detect browser properties</a>
</p>


 $("#detect_browser").click(function() {
      alert(JSON.stringify(bowser, null, '    '));
    });
```

http://www.pontikis.net/tip/?id=27

Comment: And don't use `javascript:` in `href`s, it's unnecessary and obtrusive. (Trying not to make a Mario joke...)