# Using Javascript to detect Google Chrome to switch CSS

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, browser-detection

I have been playing around with different scripts, I found one that works for everything but Chrome... this is the code I have been using to differ in .CSS files. I tried just makeing the Browser name into "Chrome" But that did not work.

```
if (browser == 'Firefox') {
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="../component/fireFoxdefault.css" />');
}
if (browser == 'Safari') {
    document.write('<'+'link rel="stylesheet" href="../component/default.css" />');
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I know this isn't part of your question (and *maybe* you have a good reason for doing this) but you shouldn't write CSS to target a browser, you should target features... for instance, Safari and Chrome should definitely not require separate CSS.  http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: How to find out if the user browser is Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565112/javascript-how-to-find-out-if-the-user-browser-is-chrome)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use the following to detect chrome:

```
var isChrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
```

Source: http://davidwalsh.name/detecting-google-chrome-javascript

**Update (2015-07-20)**:

The above solution does not always work. A more reliable solution can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625876/how-to-detect-chrome-and-safari-browser-webkit#answer-12625944) (see below). That being said, I would [avoid browser detection and go with feature detection instead](http://elijahmanor.com/does-browser-sniffing-still-have-a-place/):

```
var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
```

You can include a css file specifically for chrome like this:

```
if (isChrome) {
    document.write('<'+'link rel="stylesheet" href="../component/chromeDefault.css" />');
}
```

**UPDATE (2014-07-29):**

@gillesc has a more elegant suggestion for detecting Chrome which he posted in a comment below and it can also be viewed on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81099/safe-feature-based-way-for-detecting-google-chrome-with-javascript).

```
var isChrome = !!window.chrome
```

Comment: Alright that worked out nicely. I looked at that website and read it, but it really didn't make since for some reason with the "-1" at the end of the variable.

Comment: .indexOf returns the position of the value (browser name) in the string (userAgent). The position starts with 0. -1 is returned if the value is not found. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: `var is_chrome = !!window.chrome` is a better detection method as user agent can be spoofed.

Comment: @gillesc thanks! I have included that in the answer.

Comment: I found that chrome detection through user agent isn't reliable. For instance Opera 27 on linux includes "chrome" too in the user agent string.

Comment: Above solution doesn't give correct results for some browsers. See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125438/why-do-chrome-and-ie-put-mozilla-5-0-in-the-user-agent-they-send-to-the-server for the reason behind the incorrect result.  This link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625876/how-to-detect-chrome-and-safari-browser-webkit  provides the correct answer

Comment: @shrawan_lakhe thanks for the links, I have included the second one in my answer above

Comment: TIL, Some versions of Edge define `window.chrome`, so the vendor check is still needed

Answer (score 1):

Here are two simple methods,one using indexOf and one using test :

```
// first method 
function check_chrome_ua() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var is_chrome = /chrome/.test(ua);

    return is_chrome;
}

// second method */
function check_chrome_ua2() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var is_chrome = ua.indexOf("applewebkit/") != -1 && ua.indexOf("khtml") > - 1;

    return is_chrome;
}

alert(check_chrome_ua()); // false or true 
alert(check_chrome_ua2()); // false or true
```

After checking if chrome is in use or not with one of these two boolean functions,you can implement your method on changing the stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

**Update for Chrome on iOS**: Chrome 38 (tested on iOS 8.1) returns false on `!!window.chrome`. To fix this you can use:

```
function isChrome(){
    var windowChrome = !!window.chrome;
    if(!windowChrome){
        // Chrome iOS specific test
        var pattern = /crios/i;
        return pattern.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
    }else{
        return windowChrome;
    }
}
```

Google [reference](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent) on the matter

Comment: Chrome for iOS is just Safari, don't confuse the two.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a TypeScript error or warning. Maybe something like the following:

```
Property 'chrome' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'
```

You can check if `"chrome"` is a key of the window object by doing something like so:

```
if("chrome" in window)
```

In my code, I created a function:

```
function isChrome(){
  return "chrome" in window;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); 
$.browser.chrome = /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()); 

// Is this a version of Chrome?
if($.browser.chrome){
  userAgent = userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf('chrome/') +7);
  userAgent = userAgent.substring(0,userAgent.indexOf('.'));
  $.browser.version = userAgent;
  // If it is chrome then jQuery thinks it's safari so we have to tell it it isn't
  $.browser.safari = false;
}

// Is this a version of Safari?
if($.browser.safari){
  userAgent = userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf('safari/') +7);
  userAgent = userAgent.substring(0,userAgent.indexOf('.'));
  $.browser.version = userAgent;
}
```

Comment: dont understand why in second line you use again navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() since you have already declared it as userAgent above ;) Nice answer though

Comment: probably copy pasted above value instead of typeing