# javascript if fails

Tags: javascript, html, dom, if-statement

I do not see where my error is, If there is any

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251149/using-javascript-to-detect-google-chrome-to-switch-css
            //provera brosera
            function check_chrome_ua() {
                var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
                var is_chrome = /chrome/.test(ua);
                alert("func check_chrome_ua() " + is_chrome);
                return is_chrome;
            }
            //promena nadpisa
            function check() {
                //alert("check1");

                var check = check_chrome_ua();
                alert("var check " + check + "; func check_chrome_ua() " + check_chrome_ua());

                if (check == "false") {
                    alert("change text");
                    document.getElementById("opomena").style.color = "red";
                    document.getElementById("opomena").innerHTML = 'Warning you are not using Google Chrome';
                }
            }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body onmousemove="check()">
    <div id="opomena">Thank you for using Google Chrome.</div>

</body>
 </html>
```

Popups on Google Chrome popup says true, on Firefox says false
popup "change text" does not display in Firefox tho var check is false.

Thank you in advance for advice

Comment: pro tip, "false" is a string ;)

Comment: true == 'false'  -> false,   
false == 'false' -> false,
oh man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
if (check == "false") {
```

to

```
if (!check) {
```

or

```
if (check == false) {
```

if you really want to check for the boolean value, `false`.

The regexp, `test` method which you call at `/chrome/.test(ua)` returns a boolean, but `check == "false"` is comparing that boolean to a string.  The two are not equal.

In JavaScript, `==` is [permissive](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3) when it comes to comparing strings to objects, but not as permissive as Perl's `eq` operator.

- `0 == false`
- `false == false`
- `"false" == [false]`
- `false != "false"`
- `0 != "false"`

It's a good habit to try and use `!==` and `===` which are well-defined operators to compare primitive values.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check for boolean value false, not "false" (it's a string).

Only `if (!check)` would be enough (or more verbose version `if (check == false)` ).