# JavaScript : Execute code only if it is not google chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Safe feature-based way for detecting Google Chrome with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81099/safe-feature-based-way-for-detecting-google-chrome-with-javascript)
>   [Using Javascript to detect Google Chrome to switch CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251149/using-javascript-to-detect-google-chrome-to-switch-css)

Is there a statement that I can use with javascript, to only execute a code if the user is using a browser ***other*** than google chrome?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;

if(!is_chrome)
{
//do stuff
}
```

Edit: Not sure how this will effect chrome mobile browser.

**Second Edit:
This throws a false positive in Microsoft Edge, the below code is the updated version:**

```
var is_chrome = (typeof window.chrome === "object" && navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Edge') === -1)
```

Comment: False positive on Edge.

Comment: @Sky wanna update the answer then?

Comment: `if(typeof window.chrome === "object" && navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Edge') === -1) {alert('chrome')}`

Answer (score 9):

Sure, i use this javascript some times for checking browser support.

```
var IE6 = false /*@cc_on || @_jscript_version < 5.7 @*/
var IE7 = (document.all && !window.opera && window.XMLHttpRequest && navigator.userAgent.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('Trident/4.0') == -1) ? true : false;
var IE8 = (navigator.userAgent.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('trident/4.0') != -1);
var IE9 = (navigator.userAgent.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('trident/5.0') != -1);
var SAFARI = (navigator.userAgent.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf("safari") != -1) && (navigator.userAgent.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") == -1);
var FIREFOX = (navigator.userAgent.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox") != -1);
var CHROME = (navigator.userAgent.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") != -1);
var ANDROID= (navigator.appVersion.toString().indexOf("Android", 0)!=-1)
var MOBILE_SAFARI = ((navigator.userAgent.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf("iphone")!=-1) || (navigator.userAgent.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf("ipod")!=-1) || (navigator.userAgent.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf("ipad")!=-1)) ? true : false;
```

The in your javascript use the variables with if statements.

Comment: Unless of course someone spoofs the user agent info.

Comment: Right, How do u check it without user agent?

Answer (score 4):

Checking for the `window.chrome` property is a fairly good way to detect Chrome without relying on the user agent string:

```
if(typeof window.chrome != "object") {
    // not Chrome
} else {
    // it's Chrome (or some fork of Chromium)
}
```

Comment: False positive on Edge.

Comment: @Sky Interesting! I wonder if Edge's `window.chrome` has certain properties on it to distinguish it from Chrome's? I can't test at the moment.

Comment: Edge has even the word "chrome" in its user-agent! I manged to use this code finally: `if (typeof window.chrome === "object" && navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Edge') === -1) {alert('chrome')}`

Answer (score 0):

While other answers to this question are valid, I would warn you **against** relying on "browser sniffing" unless absolutely necessary. Check out: http://www.sitepoint.com/why-browser-sniffing-stinks/

Instead, you can use handy tools such as [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect whether a client can support  individual features.